# Specify path to tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, webpack

I am using webpack with awesome-typescript-loader in an environment with multiple tsconfig.json files. Is there a way in webpack to specify the path of the desired tsconfig.json file?

loaders:

```
{
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'],
        exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader?tsconfig=/path/to/tsconfig.json', 'angular2-template-loader'],
```

Comment: Please provide some commentary on how this solves the problem/

Comment: `loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader?configFileName=./src/tsconfig.json']` also works for me.

Comment: Looks like it's `tsconfig` in ATL 2 and `configFileName` in 3.

Answer (score 13):

Currently, loaders are a list of objects. Also, you can provide `query` parameters in a cleaner way. Instead of:

```
    loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader?configFileName=...'
```

you can have:

```
// Assuming your typescript stuff is in ./src/components:
loaders: [
  {
    test: /src\/components\/.*\.tsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
    query: {
      // Use this to point to your tsconfig.json.
      configFileName: './src/components/tsconfig.json'
    }
  },
  {
    // Another loader...
  }
]
```

**Update**

I believe `loaders` are now called `rules`. So instead of:

```
loaders: [
    ...
]
```

You would use:

```
rules: [
    ...
]
```